# Сравнивание DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

```
        Message ms = db.Messages.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == 50);
        if (ms.Date.CompareTo(Date) > 0) { Console.WriteLine("I don't understand"); }
        foreach (Message msg in db.Messages.Where(m => m.Date.CompareTo(Date)>0))
```

В базе данных есть строка сообщения с Id=50 и определенным временем(это достоверная истина). Есть Date-дата, ее шлет мне клиент, которую я же ему и отослал сообщением с Id=50(с миллисекундами). Кажется, что условие во второй строке не должно срабатывать? Оно так и есть, но в третьей, кажется подобной строке на строке с Id=50 лямбда-выражение `(m => m.Date.CompareTo(Date)>0)` выдает `true`. К тому же свойство `DateTime.Ticks` и у 50-ого сообщения и у объекта `Date` равны.

Примечание: первая и вторая строки нужны только для эксперимента, после решения проблемы их быть не должно.

Comment: Возможно проблема в том, что типы .net хранят более точное значение после запятой чем база данных. Можно попробовать сравнивать `TotalSeconds`

Comment: думаю, что проблема в том, что один Compare происходит на стороне клиента(1 и 2 строка), а второй Compare происходит на стороне SQL сервера(надо посмотреть профилировщиком, какой запрос на Where выполняется). Вот в этом вся и разница.

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov, да вы правы. Я сначала вытащил все сообщения из базы в переменную, а затем в цикле, вместо прямого обращения к базе использовал эту переменную и все заработало как надо. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разница в выполнении данных строк: 
1 и 2 строка у вас происходит **на стороне клиента**, на стороне .NET

3 же строка будет выполнятся **на стороне сервера**. Когда вы написали вот так

```
foreach (Message msg in db.Messages.Where(m => m.Date.CompareTo(Date)>0))
```

У вас сгенерится запрос, подобный вот такому

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Extent1].[time] AS [time]
    FROM [dbo].[Targets] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[time] > @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 datetime2(7)',@p__linq__0='2017-05-02 21:00:00'
```

И он у вас также срабатывать не должен, если вы никаких преобразований с полем в БД не выполняете.

Answer (score 0):

Сравнение будет корректно если обращаться к сообщениям не напрямую в базу данных. Например я сделал так:

```
IEnumerable<Message> msgs = db.Messages;
foreach (Message msg in msgs.Where(m => m.Date.CompareTo(Date) > 0))
```